# Not able to display barchart using chart.js and jquery in php program

Tags: php, jquery, chart.js, bar-chart

```
I am using chart.js in php program to print chart using jquery but not able to display chart
```

```
I have also included bootstrap files in my original code
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 400px;height:400px;">
        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400" style="color: red;"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var data1 = {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'My First dataset',
                backgroundColor: '#16a085',
                data: [10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
            }]
        };

        var options1 = {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        };

        var ctx = $('#myChart');
        var piechart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data1,options1);

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Not able to display graph using**

#### var piechart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data1,options1);

**but i can display chart using**
var piechart = new Chart(ctx,{
                type:'bar',
                data:data1 ,
                options: options1,
            });

```
But I want to display chart using 1st method
```

Comment: Why do you want to use the first method? I don't think that's a supported syntax.

Comment: I have seen some videos where 1st method works.I think 1st method is more convenient than 2nd method

Comment: And these videos use Chart.js 2.x or 1.x? I'm quite sure that's the syntax from the five year old version 1.x.

Comment: You are Possibly right

Comment: I think you're right with that statement. I think so too.